Is there any way to get the C precompiler to use a mathematical result when concatenating symbols?
I have a C macro that concatenates bits together in order to resolve to other macros. I'll demonstrate using an admittedly pointless macro called MULT which multiplies two numbers. So long as I pass in an actual literal integer to its first parameter it works. But passing in a mathematical expression triggers an error.
For example:
#define MULT_2(X) X+X
#define MULT_3(X) X+X+X
#define MULT_4(X) X+X+X+X

#define EXPAND_(A) A
#define MULT__(N, X) EXPAND_(MULT_ ## N)(X)
#define MULT_(N, X) MULT__(N, X)
#define MULT(N, X) MULT_(EXPAND_(N), X)

int main() {
    int num;

    // This works:
    num = MULT(4, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);

    // This does not:
    num = MULT(2+2, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);

    return 0;
}

(To be honest, I don't fully understand why getting this macro to work with just a literal integer requires three extra macros, MULT_, MULT__, and EXPAND_. But regardless...)
Is there anyway to rewrite this so that passing in an expression like 2+2 or 1 * 4 or 1 << 2 to its first argument will actually work?
I'm curious about the answer mainly to broaden my knowledge of C and its preprocessor. But I'm also hoping to make use of this for a project that's being written in C89, which means no variadic macros, so if there's a solution that avoids using those, I'd love to see it!

Why macros? Why not just plain (constexpr) functions?

@JesperJuhl Because I want to employ this in C where there is no constexpr, and because I want to see if I can expand my knowledge of C macros, and being able to do this would allow me to write more powerful macros.

fine, then I can remove the C++ tag

"expand my knowledge of C macros, and being able to do this would allow me to write more powerful macros" - Honestly, macros is something you should do your utmost to avoid using, not something you should try to get better at.

it would be much better to use inlined functions then

as soon as you're using concatenation like in MULT_ ## N then N HAS to contain only letters, numbers and underscores (and possibly $). So you want to do something impossible.

@Jean-FrançoisFabre If that is the case, then go ahead and submit that as an answer. "This is impossible" is certainly a valid answer to the question.

This is, for all intents and purposes, impossible. C macro token concatenation (##) does not evaluate expressions, it only merges tokens, as the name implies.
This is what the macro you've created expands to when trying to add a mathematical expression in:
#define MULT_2(X) X + X
#define MULT_3(X) X + X + X
#define MULT_4(X) X + X + X + X

#define EXPAND_(A)   A
#define MULT__(N, X) EXPAND_(MULT_##N)(X)
#define MULT_(N, X)  MULT__(N, X)
#define MULT(N, X)   MULT_(EXPAND_(N), X)

// MULT(2+2, 1)
MULT_2 + 2(1)

This is obviously not the desired effect.

Concatenation with ## pastes tokens together into a new preprocessing token. Making a string literal is a different operator, #.


Is there any way to get the C precompiler to use a mathematical result when concatenating symbols?

Yes, but you have to make the arithmetic in preprocessor, not outside of it, and then use that computed result by preprocessor to do the operation. It would look something along:
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADD_1_1  2
#define ADD_1_2  3
#define ADD_2_2  4
/* etc, bilions of combinations */
#define ADD(a, b)  ADD_##a##_##b

#define MULT_2(X) X+X
#define MULT_3(X) X+X+X
#define MULT_4(X) X+X+X+X

#define EXPAND_(A) A
#define MULT__(N, X) EXPAND_(MULT_ ## N)(X)
#define MULT_(N, X) MULT__(N, X)
#define MULT(N, X) MULT_(EXPAND_(N), X)

int main() {
    int num;
    num = MULT(4, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = MULT(ADD(2, 2), 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
}

You might be interested in boost library BOOST_PP_ADD and BOOST_PP_MUL and P99 library P99_ADD and P99_MUL (use boost).
